# extract value from object to column python

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have a output in below format

```
values = {'A': (node:A connections:{B:[0.9565217391304348], C:[0.5], D:[0], E:[0], F:[0], I:[0]}),
 'B': (node:B connections:{F:[0.7], D:[0.631578947368421], J:[0]}),
 'C': (node:C connections:{D:[0.5]})}
```

when i **print(type(values))** output is **pm4py.objects.heuristics_net.obj.HeuristicsNet**

I want to take NODE & CONNECTION, then create two columns which has all connections to individual nodes as seen below

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Nodes':['A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','C'], 'Connection':['B','C','D','E,'F','I', 'F', 'D', 'J', 'D']})
```

It is simply a combination of each node with each of its connection. I have worked on simple dictionary before, but i am unaware to extract info as required here.

How to proceed further?

Comment: something is wrong with your formatting. please check your code and post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: can u explain ?

Comment: your code is not runable as is. please fix it so that others can run it